# How can I invoke end to end tests at the command line without having to firstly execute ng serve

Tags: protractor, angular-cli, end-to-end

According to the [angular cli documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#running-end-to-end-tests) is it necessary to execute `ng serve` before invoking `ng e2e` if you want to execute end to end tests.

It would be more convenient to execute `ng e2e` only.

How would I go about executing the end to end tests without having to first execute `ng serve`?

I found the following similar question, but I'm not using gulp

[How to run e2e tests in teamcity, How to run the server in the background and run e2e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285927/how-to-run-e2e-tests-in-teamcity-how-to-run-the-server-in-the-background-and-ru)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are testing against a *local build* of your application, you have to serve it in order for Protractor to access it. We use `grunt` with the following plugins:

- [`grunt-contrib-connect`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect)
- [`grunt-protractor-runner`](https://github.com/teerapap/grunt-protractor-runner)

The `connect` and `protractor` tasks configuration:

```
connect: {
    test: {
        options: {
            base: 'dist',
            port: 9001
        }
    },
},

protractor: {
    options: {
        keepAlive: true,
        noColor: false
    },
    local: {
        options: {
            configFile: "test/e2e/config/local.conf.js"
        }
    }
},
```

And here is the `e2e` custom "macro" task which would serve the app and run the tests:

```
grunt.registerTask('e2e:local', [
    'connect:test',
    'protractor:local'
]);
```

Note that we have `baseUrl` pointing to `127.0.0.1:9001` inside the "local" protractor config.